# what does $ mean in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I have some confusion in variable declaration.

> what does $ mean in heroes$

Angular 4

```
export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;
private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

constructor(
 private heroSearchService: HeroSearchService,
 private router: Router) {}
```

Angular 7+

```
 export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
 heroes$: Observable<Hero[]>;
 private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
 constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}

     // Push a search term into the observable stream.
          search(term: string): void {
          console.log(term);
            this.searchTerms.next(term);
        }
```

- i have confusion in angular 7 ver where
  heroes is assigned with $ variable.
- i tried to remove $ symbol from var then code doesn't works.
- any suggestion is most welcome

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a convention followed for Observables. Here's what the [**Angular Docs**](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables) have to say about it:

> Because Angular applications are mostly written in TypeScript, you will typically know when a variable is an observable. Although the Angular framework does not enforce a naming convention for observables, you will often see observables named with a trailing “$” sign.
>
> This can be useful when scanning through code and looking for observable values. Also, if you want a property to store the most recent value from an observable, it can be convenient to simply use the same name with or without the “$”.

There's no harm in not following it as such. But since it is a recommendation, it's good to follow.

#### UPDATE

Conventions evolve over time depending on the past experience of developers. This particular convention was [**committed on the 10th of Jan, 2018**](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/21423/commits/31ee1949d4ea746acf8156828c97138d8c7e4563)

So yeah, this convention was added to the Docs after Angular 5 and there are high chances that you weren't using it while working in Angular 4.

Also, the syntax for Rxjs has also changed significantly after the upgrade to Rxjs 5.5 in Angular 5(not sure about the exact version). So you might want to check how the syntax of Rxjs has changed over time. There's a nifty tool to help you with that. Check out [**RxJS Explorer 2.0**:
Learn. Compare. Update.](https://reactive.how/rxjs/explorer)

Comment: It depends on the name of the variable. If you have `$` suffixed, then it should be `$` suffixed everywhere for that variable. It's probably not working because you forgot to remove `$` from the template where you're using this variable, probably with an `async` pipe. If you still feel that there's a confusion, I'd request you to create a Sample StackBlitz replicating this issue so that I can figure out what the issue actually is.

Comment: but in angular 4 has no $ convention when used with observables

Comment: it still doesn't clear my dout i have  worked in angular 4 but when i update to version 7 there is confusion in syntax

Comment: thanks sidd that means rxjs has changed some syntax  in  its lib i was using "rxjs": "6.3.3",